# Adding a share function for webView - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, uiwebview

I have an app which display a table view. When a user taps on a cell the view goes to the detail view. The detail view has a UIWebView, based on which cell is tapped the detail view opens a online PDF file within the web view. The PDF is stored on the server.

I am trying to add a share function within my app so a user can share that link of the PDF they are viewing in the detail view via email or text.

I am trying to add this:

[image]

I have not tried anything yet mostly because I have no clue where to begin. My question is that whether it is possible to implement this, if so can you guide me in the right direction.

P.s ( I only want to share via Email OR Text) NOT via social network

Comment: Have you got any answer for your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can store PDF url in member variable so that you can use that variable and pass while sharing on different social media.

Comment: I am already saving the URL in variable. I am just not sure how to implement the "share" feature as shown in the image in my question and share it from their. I don't want to share it to social network. Only email or text.